# .net to Java - will serialized XML work?

Tags: java, .net

Our group is primarily Java developers with a few .NET folks like me.

We have a new app that we're considering and are thinking of using .NET on the front-end and Java for the app server.

What is the best way to communicate? Soap can be slow. I don't think that Serialized XML will work. I seem to recall that it is proprietary for .NET. Or will it work?

Comment: I guess that's the idea behind xml - to provide interoperability

Comment: Given that SOAP is simply XML, if you're concerned about SOAP being slow that concern should also be applied to XML.  Todd's suggestions are good lightweight alternatives.

Comment: When you say 'Serialized XML', are you expecting that Java and .Net's notion of a serialized object represented as XML are compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML serialization is just that - XML. I can't immediately think of why there should be any issues with this idea, as long as both the .NET and Java setups are working against the same schema and objects. XML is an open format.

I think **binary** serialization is proprietary to .NET, and is not exchangeable with other platforms.

Comment: Yes, it was binary serialization. Thanks you jogged my memory

Comment: Are Class Libraries (DLL) doable in JAVA? If so, you could just reference your JAVA library to your .NET project and call the functions from it, otherwise perhaps only referencing these functions from the GAC or COM so you might use the [DllImport()] tag in your .Net code. Just another idea which would save you from doing this HDD File IO thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_(web_service_protocol)) can provide multi-platform alternatives to SOAP.  You can find some details concerning protocol buffers for .Net [here](http://zvolkov.com/blog/post/2009/07/28/Google-Protocol-Buffers.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON as format for communication. Its structured, less complicated, and lightweight.

Comment: +1 to this, I have used [JSON.NET (Newtonsoft)](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) on the .NET side and [Google's GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) on the java side and it seems to work for Dictionaries, Maps, Sets, Lists, Date, and primitive types with very little configuration involved.